# Windows Events Forwarding: Error Code 2150859195

Tags: windows, events

I have been struggling to find a solution for the following errors when I configure Forwarding Windows Events to a collector using source initiated http (I followed most blogs on configuration). The error is:

ErrorCode 2150859195 
  ErrorMessage The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config.

So far, I have tried to add the collector IP to the client's TrustedHosts and vice versa; add NetworkService account to the Event Log Readers group.

Answer (score 0):

I felt lucky to figure it out and wanted to share here to help others. At least, after I made the following change on the source computers, I worked well now.

1. use FQDN not the IP address of the collector. I do not know why
2. enable WinRM listeners policy, set both IPv4 and IPv6 value to *